# Do Yorick's Ghouls (and other Spawnable entities) trigger Ravenous Hunter?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do Yorick's ghouls and the damage they deal count as ability damage, and specifically, would they trigger the rune Ravenous Hunter, and heal me based on the damage they deal? I can not find conclusive evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ravenous Hunter is a *Drain Effect*, so its apply to **all** damage sources.

Liandry's Torment has 2 passives: **Madness** stacks w/ any damage you deal; **Torment** is applied by any *Ability Damage*, so if your ability deal damage to a unity torment will proc.

Yorick's ghouls **do apply** spell damage, so yes it works.

Comment: best site about league imo

https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Yorick
https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Liandry's_Torment